How Can I Set filterQuality with CachedNetworkImageProvider in Flutter?
I’m working on a Flutter app and using CachedNetworkImageProvider to load images from the web. I want to set filterQuality to FilterQuality.low to improve performance, similar to how it works with CachedNetworkImage.
Here’s how I’m using CachedNetworkImageProvider:
PhotoView(
  imageProvider: CachedNetworkImageProvider(imageSrc),
);

But I can’t figure out how to apply filterQuality in this setup. With CachedNetworkImage, it’s straightforward:
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: imageSrc,
  filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
);

Is there a way to set filterQuality when using CachedNetworkImageProvider?
For reference, I’m using the photo_view: photo_view and cached_network_image: cached_network_image.
I tried using CachedNetworkImageProvider with PhotoView in Flutter, aiming to apply filterQuality like I do with CachedNetworkImage. I expected to be able to set filterQuality directly for better performance, but couldn’t find a way to do it with CachedNetworkImageProvider.
